# android: add empty tab first and set content later

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

In the example below, is there a way to add an empty tab first and set the content later when args value is not null?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    .........//more code
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     args.putSerializable("arguments", object);
     ..................

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"),
        Tab1Fragment.class, args);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2"),
        Tab2Fragment.class, args);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab3"),
        Tab3Fragment.class, args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per android api documentation of FragmentTabHost, add the tab when the argue is not null and use [setup](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) method